# What is the word for "to go back (of time)"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s the word for “to go back” of time? I’m trying to say that time cannot *go back*.  For example:

> I wish I were a child again, but time does not “go back”.

Comment: You can't turn back time.

Comment: @Jim Is there also a single word for this?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Time doesn't rewind.

Comment: We don't have a word for the reverse of "time's arrow" because outside of [Feynmann diagrams](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) there's nothing remotely approaching a real-world referent. Nor can we imagine what it would be "like" enough to give it a name. *Time* cannot be *antitime*.

Comment: Btw, [Here's one of Cher's songs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEszTzdUMcY) - [*If I could turn back time*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Could_Turn_Back_Time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Things are ever changing and time never retreats*.

> I wish I was a child again, but **sadly, time never retreats**.

*Time never retreats and is one of those rare concepts that is linked uniquely to Eternity. The Human Being is an equal and rare creation that shares a special connection with eternity and time.* ([Time Management](http://www.guidespot.com/guides/time_management))

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here I would use the phrase "turn back the clock".

**E.g.**

> I wish I was a child again, but there is no way I can turn back the clock.

Comment: As a side note, "e.g." means "for example". "For e.g." means "for for example", which does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The noun *[regress](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regress#Noun)* (“The act of passing back; passage back; return; retrogression” or “The power or liberty of passing back”) can be used in sentences like “We have no power to regress time” or “Time has no regress”.

Various metaphors for the passage of time imply time cannot be turned back, that it is a one-way street.  The dozens of metaphors at  [grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/rhetoricstyle/a/x.htm) and [xamuel.com](http://www.xamuel.com/ten-metaphors-for-time/) include characterizations of time as:

> •  A river.  “We navigate it in our boats, having some minor ability to resist the currents but ultimately bound ever forward by the waves.”  (Also see below re Heraclitus.)
>   • An arrow. “The arrow metaphor emphasizes fate and momentum. ... the dart is already released; there’s no recalling it, or changing its path.”
>   • a Thief, a Trap, a Stream, a Prison, etc.
>   • a Circus. “Time is a circus, always packing up and moving away.” (Ben Hecht)

Time as a flowing river is a well-worn metaphor.  In about 500 BCE [Heraclitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus#Panta_rhei.2C_.22everything_flows.22) of [Ephesus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephesus) wrote:

> ποταμοῖσι τοῖσιν αὐτοῖσιν ἐμϐαίνουσιν, ἕτερα καὶ ἕτερα ὕδατα ἐπιρρεῖ.
>   and
>   Ποταμοῖς τοῖς αὐτοῖς ἐμβαίνομέν τε καὶ οὐκ ἐμβαίνομεν, εἶμέν τε καὶ οὐκ εἶμεν.

which in translation resemble

> Ever-newer waters flow on those who step into the same rivers.
>   and
>   We both step and do not step in the same rivers. We are and are not.

Answer (score 1):

*Revert* comes to mind, from Latin *revertere*, "turn back".

> Time cannot be reverted.

But I'm not a native English speaker, so don't trust me.

Comment: *Revertere* is Latin. French would be *revertir*.

Answer (score 0):

Time does not *run backward* (or *backwards*). Perform the Google search [ [`time run backward`](http://www.google.com/search?q=time%20run%20backward) ] to see that this phrase is commonly used in academic writing and mainstream publications such as *Scientific American* and *Time Magazine*.

Comment: *time run backward* 60M; "*time run backward*" 150k; excluding "Does Time Run Backward in Other Universes?" 1,020.